# Query: Azure function app memory consumption

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I am using the Azure function app as a microservices. There are a total of 8 microservices deployed in the same App Service plan (EP1). The microservice is developed in .net core 7 isolated (out of process). This is consuming 90% of memory.

The microservices mostly have APIs (endpoints) for Angular applications. Few work for integration, to sync data from external sources to cosmos DB. For this, we have implemented a few queue background processors of the FUnction app and a timer trigger function.

I observed each Function App is consuming memory from the range (of 120-400 MB) on low traffic.

I have the following queries-

- How can I check if the performance is optimum for the function app?
- Changing from Function to Web API, will it make the microservices lighter?
- Does out-of-process FA consume more memory? I am observing it is quite heavy compared to in-process FAs.
- How can I confirm there is no memory leak in the Function apps? I am following SOLID principal standards including proper disposal of clients [HTTP (singleton), ServiceBus CLinet, cosmos, etc,].
- Is the Function app the right approach to building APIs (microservices)? Should we migrate to Web API? Will this solve the memory issue?
- If we containerize the microservices, which will be best for the
  above scenarios? Function app or Web API?

**Note:-** The plan is to move to AKS in the next quarter, most probably in March next year.

As memory consumption is high, service bus connections are closing and cosmos change feed triggers are failing.

Below are the dependencies for the heaviest FA.

```
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.CosmosDb" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.Tables" Version="12.8.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.16.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.18.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.13.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.15.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks" Version="7.0.11" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="7.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.0.2" />
```

Please suggest the most suitable solution for the above scenario. I am
collecting data points like migrating to Web API will help solve memory issues or not. I know deploying function apps in different ASPs will solve the issue but I want to reduce Infrastructure costs as much as possible before moving to AKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - How can I check if the performance is optimum for the function app?   How can I confirm there is no memory leak in the Function apps? I am following SOLID principal standards including proper disposal of clients [HTTP (singleton), ServiceBus CLinet, cosmos, etc,].

You can check the **performance and memory leak** of your **Function App** by connecting your Function app with **Application Insights**, in the **Diagnose and Solve Problems** section and **Azure Monitor** section:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Another alternative to mitigate the memory leak is to Scale your Functions App to a Dedicated App Service plan instead of using Consumption based plan.

[image]

You can also avoid using same storage account for your multiple Function Apps and Avoid using blocking calls, Use Async code that waits until the operation is completed.

> - Changing from Function to Web API, will it make the microservices lighter?

Changing from Function to Web API won't make the microservices lighter. As Functions can be Deployed in Azure Container Apps and Instances. Web API is better when you want to have a control on Middleware, dependency injection and routing. But Azure Functions supports Dependency Injection too.  And you can add custom middleware to interact with Databases in your Azure Function Triggers. In-fact you can call external Web and Rest API's in your Function and perform event based tasks.

> - Does out-of-process FA consume more memory? I am observing it is quite heavy compared to in-process FAs.

Out-of-process Function Apps consume more memory than in-process Function Apps as they run in a separate process from the host process. This means that out-of-process Function Apps require more memory to run, as they need to load the .NET runtime and other dependencies into memory.

> - If we containerize the microservices, which will be best for the above scenarios? Function app or Web API?

As Function App itself works on serverless architecture it can work as a Containerized App very efficiently. You can containerized your Function App and run it from AKS by referring this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda). And in Function App you only pay for the time your triggers are active, As it is based on a serverless architecture. Even Web API can be containerized with Azure Container services.

Regarding the dependencies for the heaviest FA, consider the following:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks" Version="3.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```